# How to dissociate WAF from Azure application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

How to dissociate WAF from Azure application gateway?

I selected the WAF and clicked on associated application gateways. Selected the application gateway that needs to be dissociated from the WAF.

but the dissociate link is disabled and Azure gives the following pop up:

Deselect application gateway(s). To disassociate the selected application gateway, associate the gateway to a different WAF policy.

and I am not able to add a new WAF policy on the application gateway

Answer (score 0):

I created Application Gateway and associated my application gateway to WAF policy and got same error as below:

```
 Deselect application gateway(s). To disassociate the selected application gateway, associate the gateway to a different WAF policy.
```

[image]

To disassociate WAF from Azure Application Gateway create separate ***Web Application Firewall policies (WAF)*** on creating WAF policy select your application gateway WAF v2 click on check box *Apply the policy configuration than the current setting*
[image]
.

[image]

After creating WAF policy, In policy 1 once refreshed Application gateway is disassociated like below:

[image]

In policy 2 Application gateway is associated successfully like below:

[image]